# Multiple JQuery Click event on li

Tags: jquery, accordion, pie-chart

Using jquery.easypiechart.js with a Jquery accordion I'm trying to use the same function more than once within separate listed items. Each listed time has an easypiechart and over time the li's will increase. For now I'm using psuedo-classes in my script for each li but obviously this is limited to a set number which will eventually be surpassed.

Code as follows...

**HTML of example listed item**

```
<li class="st-open" style="height: 491px;">
    <a class="st-animate" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Stat 10">Stat 10</a>
    <div class="st-content entry-content" itemprop="articleBody" style="display: block;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="chart" data-percent="86"><span class="percent">86</span>
                <canvas height="220" width="220" style="height: 110px; width: 110px;"></canvas>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$("li:nth-of-type(1) .st-animate").click(function() {
        $('li:nth-of-type(1) .chart').easyPieChart({
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            animate: 5000,
            onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
                $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
            }
        });
    });
    $("li:nth-of-type(2) .st-animate").click(function() {
        $('li:nth-of-type(2) .chart').easyPieChart({
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            animate: 5000,
            onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
                $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
            }
        });
    });
// and so on...
```

How can I solve the issue of not using psuedo-classes. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(".st-animate").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.chart').easyPieChart({
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        animate: 5000,
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
});
```

Sample example:-

```js
$(".st-animate").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).closest('li').find('.chart').data('percent'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="st-open" style="height: 491px;">
  <a class="st-animate" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Stat 10">Stat 10</a>
  <div class="st-content entry-content" itemprop="articleBody" style="display: block;">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
      aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
      culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      <span class="chart" data-percent="86"><span class="percent">86</span>
        <canvas height="220" width="220" style="height: 110px; width: 110px;"></canvas>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="st-open" style="height: 491px;">
  <a class="st-animate" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Stat 10">Stat 10</a>
  <div class="st-content entry-content" itemprop="articleBody" style="display: block;">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
      labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      <span class="chart" data-percent="87"><span class="percent">86</span>
        <canvas height="220" width="220" style="height: 110px; width: 110px;"></canvas>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```